# Perl Globbing a Variable stops on first match

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments, glob

I'm trying to loop over some files in my directory in Perl. Let's say my current directory contains: song0.txt, song1.txt, song2.txt, song3.txt, song4.txt.

I supply "song?.txt" as an argument to my program.

When I do:

```
foreach $file (glob "$ARGV[0]") {
    printf "$file\n";
}
```

It stops after printing "song0.txt".

However, if I replace "$ARGV[0]" with "song?.txt", it prints out all 5 of them as expected. Why doesn't Perl glob work with variables and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Supply argument in double quotes - `perl script.pl "song?.txt"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call your program with `song?.txt` the shell expands that `?` so

```
prog.pl song?.txt -->  prog.pl song0.txt song1.txt ...
```

Thus `"$ARGV[0]"` in the program is `song0.txt` and there is nothing for Perl's `glob` to do with it.

So you'd either do

```
foreach my $file (@ARGV) { }
```

and call the program with `prog.pl song?.txt`, or do the globbing in Perl

```
foreach my $file (glob "song?.txt") { ... }
```

where now Perl's [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) will construct the list of files using `?` in the pattern.

Which of the two is "better" depends on the context. But I'd rather submit to a program a straight-up list of files, if that is an equal option, than get entangled in `glob`-ing patterns in the program.

Also note that Perl's `glob` is an ancient "demon", with "interesting" behaviors in some cases.

Comment: Of course, one could also use `prog.pl 'song?.txt'` with the original program (but why?)